# CosmosDB - Gremlin - high memory usagage with query containing limit() step

Tags: performance, azure-cosmosdb, gremlin, gremlin-server

I want to retrive a large amount of items but using limit clause:

`g.V().hasLabel('foo').as('f').limit(5000).order().by('f_Id',incr).by('f_bar',incr).select('f').unfold().dedup()`

This query takes very long time and consumes about 800 MB memory to download the collection

Whan i use below query:

`g.V().hasLabel('foo').as('f').has('propA','ValueA').has('propB','ABC').limit(5000).order().by('f_Id',incr).by('f_bar',incr).select('f').unfold().dedup()`

it is faster and consumes less memory around 500 MB to download this collection but still high.

My Qestion is how to optimize the first query with just limit if i do not want to filter by Properties A and B.

Second Question why there is such difference in memory size between those two results? In both queries i download 5000 items to memory. What could be possible way to reduce this consumption.

I use GremlinDriver for .Net.

Comment: just to clarify, are you saying that your data is such that `g.V().hasLabel('foo').has('propA','ValueA').has('propB','ABC').limit(5000)` on its own produces 5000 results? therefore there are 5000 or more vertices with label "foo" and those values for "propA" and "propB"?

Comment: @stephenmallette yes that is correct

Answer (score 0):

I'm not expert at CosmosDB optimization but from a Gremlin perspective when I look at this traversal:

```
g.V().hasLabel('foo').as('f').
  limit(5000).order().by('f_Id',incr).by('f_bar',incr).
  select('f').unfold().dedup()
```

I wonder why you wouldn't just write it as:

```
g.V().hasLabel('foo').limit(5000).order().by('f_Id',incr).by('f_bar',incr)
```

Meaning, you want 5000 "foo" vertices ordered a certain way. The need to use the "f" step label and `unfold()` seem unnecessary and I don't see how you could end up with duplicates so you can drop `dedup()`. I'm not sure if those changes will make any difference to how CosmosDB processes things but it certainly removes some unneeded processing.

I'd also wonder if you need to pair down the data returned in your vertices. Right now you're returning all the properties for each vertex. If you don't need all of those it might be better to be more specific and transform the data to the form your application requires:

```
g.V().hasLabel('foo').limit(5000).order().by('f_Id',incr).by('f_bar',incr).
  valueMap('name','age')
```

That should help reduce serialization costs.